# Ruby ORM inserted records

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I've run into a problem with my ruby ORM using sqlite3

my orm has a save function that saves a record in the database and sets the objects instance id to the id of the new record:

```
 def save
    sql = "INSERT INTO #{table_name_for_insert} (#{col_names_for_insert}) VALUES (#{values_for_insert})"
    DB[:conn].execute(sql)
    @id = DB[:conn].execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM #{table_name_for_insert}")[0][0]
end
```

- `table_name_for_insert` returns "students"
- `col_names_for_insert`
  returns  "name, grade"
- `values_for_insert` returns "'Sam', '11'"

This all "works" *per se*, however, when `SELECT * FROM students` is run after the save method the record returned is:

```
[{"id" => 1,
'name" => "Sam", 
"grade => 11,
0 => 1, 
1 => "Sam",
2 => 11 }]
```

I expect the first 3 columns but I have no idea why the last three exist.

If anyone knows whats going on i appreciate it, I'm sure this is a stupid mistake on my part.

Comment: Can you show your `students` table schema, and show the code that ran the `SELECT * FROM students` and how the result was observed?

Comment: I used pry after the last line of the method, once in pry i ran
DB[:conn].execute("SELECT * FROM students")

Comment: The driver probably returns the numeric keyed columns. Inspect the query result as you receive it from the driver.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by using an improper version of the splite3 gem.
After that was fixed I no longer had the issue of the additional columns.